# Why are response IDs for UDS requests always the Request ID + 8?

Tags: diagnostics

We have a supplier pushing back on us requiring that the UDS Request/Response IDs be separated by 8.  (i.e. for a given Request ID, the associated Response ID shall be the Request ID + 8.)  We've done this since it follows suit with the given examples in ISO 15765-4:2011, Table 6.

We've tried explained that we're just referencing Table 6, but there is still a strong push for an actual ISO requirement that points this out.

I'd like to be able to point to a specific section in an ISO spec for UDS that calls this out.  If that doesn't exist, I'd like to know where this comes from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ISO 15765-4 describes the communication for On-Board Diagnostics (OBD) of emission related systems.

For this use case a range of CAN-IDs has been reserved. The range contains the IDs from `0x7E0` to `0x7EF`, i.e. 16 IDs

The standard assumes that there are at most 8 emission related ECUs and thus reserves one ID for physical request and response for each of these 8 ECUs. Requests are between `0x7E0` and `0x7E7`, the responses between `0x7E8` and `0x7EF`.

It has been defined that, as you have said, for this use-case the response ID is request ID + 0x8. This is the definition for OBD. All OBD testers can rely on the ECUs using these addresses for communicating the emission related data.

Having said this, this is in no way related to UDS - ISO calls this `enhanced diagnostics`. For enhanced diagnostics the manufacturer can freely choose the CAN-IDs on which requests (both physical and functional) and responses transmitted. The CAN-IDs are determined by the network design of your vehicle.

So in short, there is no ISO or other norm imposing any restrictions on the CAN-IDs for UDS, apart from the fact that enhanced diagnostics must not interfere with the legislated OBD communication.